# Getting data from 3 tables that related to each other and displaying them in a template - django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I want to implement a survey in my site. I created 3 tables for that and below is the snippet for each model:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    klass_id = models.ForeignKey(Klass, verbose_name='class', related_name='s_klass', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='description', blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='end date')


class SurveyOptions(models.Model):
    survey_id = models.ForeignKey(Survey, verbose_name='survey name', related_name='s_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='option title')

class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    option_id = models.ForeignKey(SurveyOptions, verbose_name='option name', related_name='s_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Profile, verbose_name='responser', related_name='responser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date', auto_now_add=True)
```

After users response to the survey, I want to get survey results and display them to users in template. I want to show survey question, survey options and survey responses(each option and its percent).

What do I write in `views.py` and what do I write in template?

The `Klass` in the first model refers to a model. and when i go to page related to each `Klass`, I must see all surveys of the `Klass`.

`Klass` refers to university classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like putting everything to do with data into the model, so this would be my approach.  Note that I have removed your _id as otherwise you end up referring to Option.survey_id.id in order to get the id or Option.survey_id.text which is even more confusing.

In models.py::

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass, verbose_name='class', related_name='s_klass', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='description', blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='end date')

    @property
    def options(self):
        return SurveyOptions.objects.filter(survey=self)



class SurveyOptions(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, verbose_name='survey name', related_name='s_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='option title')


    @property
    def response_as_pct(self):
        option_responses = SurveyResponse.objects.filter(option = self).count()
        survey_responses = SurveyResponse.objects.filter(option__in = self.survey.options).count()

        # will need to handle edge cases of 0 options or 0 responses and may not want to multiply by 100
        return option_responses/survey_responses * 100

class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey(SurveyOptions, verbose_name='option name', related_name='s_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Profile, verbose_name='responser', related_name='responser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date', auto_now_add=True)
```

In Views::

```
surveys = Survey.objects.all()   or filter as required

render in whatever way passing surveys
```

In Template::

```
{% for survey in surveys %}
      {% for option in survey.options %}
             {{ option.text }} - {{ option.response_as_pct }}
      {% endfor %}
{% endor %}
```